# Accessing Azure Storage from stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We have recently migrated our data from on-premises SQL Server ( SQL Server 2012 ) to Azure Database.  Refer to one such table that we had in on-premises database named, 'Customer'

```
Customer
-------------------------------------------------------------
id   | name     |   GUID         |        ProfilePhoto
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       Name1     xxxx-yyyy-zzz           <<BLOB DATA>>
-------------------------------------------------------------
2       Name2     xxxx-yyyy-zzB           <<BLOB DATA>>
-------------------------------------------------------------
3       Name3     xxxx-yyyy-zzA           <<BLOB DATA>>
```

Also we have a stored procedure in database called GetProfilePhoto_sp(guid)
which accepts GUID and returns corresponding ProfilePhoto which belongs to 'Customer' table.

After migrating '`Customer`' table and `GetProfilePhoto_sp(guid)` on to Azure SQL server we don't have 'ProfilePhoto' column as we have made decision to store unstructured data (i.e. ProfilePhoto ) onto Azure Blob Storage.

Now our GetProfilePhoto_sp is point towards an invalid column as we don't have 'ProfilePhoto' column anymore.
Do we have any provision to access Azure Storage from GetProfilePhoto_sp  Stored Procedure?

Comment: What user2243747 is asking is very clear: can a SQL Database store proc access Blob storage?

Comment: Agreed - not sure why this is unclear. The question is about accessing Azure Storage from a SQL Database stored procedure. **Update** I looked at the edit history, and it appears this was put on hold before the question was edited with more detail.